# redux-observable and rxjs. Converting promise to Observable - epic gets called only once

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I'm using redux-observable to handle an action:

```
export const createPaymentMethod =
  (getBraintreeToken: (Object) => Promise<*>, cardholderName: string) => ({
    type: CREATE_PAYMENT_METHOD,
    getBraintreeToken: () => getBraintreeToken({ cardholderName }),
  });

const mapBraintreeError = err => Observable.of({
  type: CREATE_PAYMENT_METHOD + FAILURE,
  error: { response: err.message },
});

export const createPaymentMethodEpic = (action$: any, store: ReduxState) =>
  action$.ofType(CREATE_PAYMENT_METHOD)
    .switchMap(({ getBraintreeToken }) => Observable.fromPromise(getBraintreeToken()))
    .switchMap(({ nonce }) =>
      ajax(api.createPaymentMethod(store.billings.info.customer_id, nonce))
        .mapSuccess(CREATE_PAYMENT_METHOD)
        .mapFailure(CREATE_PAYMENT_METHOD),
    )
    .catch(mapBraintreeError);
```

What I do is I intentionally make `getBraintreeToken()` Promise fail. This results in epic execute `catch` function and returning `CREATE_PAYMENT_METHOD + FAILURE` action. Which is what I intended.

The problem is when I try to call epic the second time. It doesn't execute...

**EDIT:**
I have converted the epic and it seems to work now, however, I still don't understand why the first example was broken (actually I like more the flat structure of the first epic).

```
export const createPaymentMethodEpic = (action$: any, store: ReduxState) =>
  action$.ofType(CREATE_PAYMENT_METHOD)
    .switchMap(({ getBraintreeToken }) =>
      Observable.fromPromise(getBraintreeToken())
        .switchMap(({ nonce }) =>
          ajax(api.createPaymentMethod(store.billings.info.customer_id, nonce))
            .mapSuccess(CREATE_PAYMENT_METHOD)
            .mapFailure(CREATE_PAYMENT_METHOD),
        )
        .catch(mapBraintreeError),
    );
```

Comment: Not to take anything away from @martin's answer, but I'm wondering if you can use a `mapTo` or `map` to avoid using error catching as the primary path. Depends on what's inside `getBraintreeToken()` and how the error message is generated. Could you post `getBraintreeToken()` (if still hunting for optimization).

Comment: Hi @RichardMatsen. I get `getBraintreeToken` from external api, so I would probably have to wrap it in some other promise to avoid catch block...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the first version is that the `error` notification reaches the `switchMap` operator that invokes its error logic which causes the chain to dispose.

It needs to be like this because an Observable emits zero or one `error` notifications but never more.

For more detailed explanation see [The Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html).

> An Observable may make zero or more OnNext notifications, each representing a single emitted item, and it may then follow those emission notifications by either an OnCompleted or an OnError notification, but not both. **Upon issuing an OnCompleted or OnError notification, it may not thereafter issue any further notifications**.

In the second version of your code you put the `catch` operator inside a callback to `switchMap`. The one `error` notifications rule is applied here as well but the callback is called for every value so even when the inner Observable emits an error it's caught (and converted into `next`) and then it's replaced by a new inner Observable.

Comment: Thanks @martin. Before I try to understand it, is it possible to make the second epic more “flat”? As it starts to remind me of callback hell.